# Tape vs screw joining 4" duct

Tags: ducts

When joining 4" round duct, like for fart fans or dryers, is it sufficient to just use sealant and aluminum tape but no screw or should I be using screws also? It seems that the tape alone would be good enough for this relatively low duty function.

Answer (score 4):

Tape is not a mechanical fastener. It is a sealant. It is not acceptable as a way of connecting duct. The options are screws, hose clamps or zip ties depending on temperature.

I have used hose clamps to connect all the metal duct on my dryer exhaust. For the bathroom fan it will be a combination of screws and zip ties as there will be some insulated flex duct.

Also when sealing ducts you may only use one method of sealant either mastic or tape. You can't use both. They aren't rated or listed for use together.